# Move whitespace to the localizable string for review option's description

Tags: feature-request, review, localization

Consider the Low Quality Posts review:

> [image: lqp]

The spaces after the bold text currently are hardcoded, i.e. I can't remove/change them via Transifex. Hence in Stack Overflow in Russian we see an ugly whitespaces before comma (we need the comma before "if" word):

> [image: ru-lqp]

Translation now is not consistent so don't draw your attention on unmarked sentances.

My request is to add whitespace into the localizable string and allow translators achieve better results. E.g. [the string](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263073?key=860bd3b169643f4a479bc0fb46f3a66d) *"if nothing is wrong with this answer"* will be *" if nothing is wrong with this answer"* (space added to the localizable string).